# Magento 2 : Javascript in phtml file not loaded

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I've just created a phtml file with CSS, HTML and Javascript code in it.
The Javascript does not get executed even tho I said `<script type="text/javascript">`.

What should I do? I also want to create a module where the javascript code is in the `.phtml` file.

Thanks a lot.

It's currently like that and doesn't work properly (only timer works)

```
<style>#progress_bar{margin-top:15px}.progressbar.progressbar{background:#ffe8e8;border:0px solid whitesmoke;height:11px}.progressbar.progressbar div{background:#d95350;height:11px}.progressbar.progressbar.active div{-webkit-animation:2s linear 0s normal none infinite running progress-bar-stripes;animation:2s linear 0s normal none infinite running progress-bar-stripes}.progress-striped.progressbar.progressbar div{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));background-size:40px 40px}.items-count{margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px}.count{color:#a94442;padding:1px}.items-count p{padding-bottom:5px;margin:0;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:700;text-align:center;font-family:"Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif}.progressbar{position:relative;display:block;background-color:#ca0000;border:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:15px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)}.progressbar > div{background-color:#ca0000;width:0;margin-bottom:0;height:15px}.progressbar > div.less-than-ten{background-color:#ca0000 !important}#clock-ticker{display:block;margin-bottom:15px}#clock-ticker .block{position:relative;color:#000;font-weight:bold;float:left;text-align:center;width:25%}#clock-ticker .block .flip-top{width:88px;height:39px;line-height:40px;font-size:40px;text-align:center}#clock-ticker .block .label,span.flip-top{color:#000;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;font-size:14px;text-transform:uppercase;width:88px;line-height:25px;font-family:"Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif}</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"], function ($) {



        function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);}

// Settings are here
var total_items = 50;
var d = new Date();
var min_items_left = 12;
var max_items_left = 20;
var remaining_items = randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left, max_items_left);
var min_of_remaining_items = 1;
var decrease_after = 1.7; 
var decrease_after_first_item = 0.17; 


// Davy Jones' Locker
(function($){$.fn.progressbar=function(){var a="<p>Hurry! Only <span class='count'>"+remaining_items+"</span> left in stock.</p>"+"<div class='progressbar'><div style='width:100%'></div></div>";this.addClass('items-count');this.html(a+this.html());updateMeter(this);var b=this;setTimeout(function(){remaining_items--;if(remaining_items<min_of_remaining_items){remaining_items=randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left,max_items_left)}$('.count').css('background-color','#CE0201');$('.count').css('color','#fff');setTimeout(function(){$('.count').css('background-color','#fff');$('.count').css('color','#CE0201')},1000*60*0.03);b.find(".count").text(remaining_items);updateMeter(b)},1000*60*decrease_after_first_item);setInterval(function(){remaining_items--;if(remaining_items<min_of_remaining_items){remaining_items=randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left,max_items_left)}$('.count').css('background-color','#CE0201');$('.count').css('color','#fff');setTimeout(function(){$('.count').css('background-color','#fff');$('.count').css('color','#CE0201')},1000*60*0.03);b.find(".count").text(remaining_items);updateMeter(b)},1000*60*decrease_after)};function updateMeter(a){var b=100*remaining_items/total_items;if(remaining_items<10){a.find('.progressbar div:first').addClass('less-than-ten')}a.find('.progressbar').addClass('active progress-striped');setTimeout(function(){myanimate(a.find('.progressbar div:first'),b);a.find('.progressbar').removeClass('active progress-striped')},1000)}}(jQuery));function myanimate(a,b){var c=0;var d=parseInt(a.closest('.progressbar').css('width'));var e=Math.floor(100*parseInt(a.css('width'))/d);if(e>b){c=e}function frame(){if(e>b){c--}else{c++}a.css('width',c+'%');if(c==b||c<=0||c>=100)clearInterval(f)}var f=setInterval(frame,40)} $(document).ready(function(){$("#progress_bar").progressbar();var tag="ctdn-12-12".match(/\d+/g);var hour=14;var theDaysBox=$("#numdays");var theHoursBox=$("#numhours");var theMinsBox=$("#nummins");var theSecsBox=$("#numsecs");var d=new Date();var n=d.getDay();var date=1;var gg=0;var hh=0;var ii=0;var nsec=0-d.getSeconds();if(nsec<0){nsec=60-d.getSeconds();gg=1}var nmin=0-d.getMinutes()-gg;if(nmin<0){nmin=60-d.getMinutes()-gg;hh=1}var nhrs=14-d.getHours()-hh;if(nhrs<0){nhrs=38-d.getHours()-hh;ii=1}var ndat=date-1;if(ndat<0){var mmon=d.getMonth();ndat=30+date-d.getDate()-ii}theSecsBox.html(nsec);theMinsBox.html(nmin);theHoursBox.html(nhrs);theDaysBox.html(ndat);var refreshId=setInterval(function(){var e=theSecsBox.text();var a=theMinsBox.text();var c=theHoursBox.text();var b=theDaysBox.text();if(e==0&&a==0&&c==0&&b==0){}else{if(e==0&&a==0&&c==0){theDaysBox.html(b-1);theHoursBox.html("23");theMinsBox.html("59");theSecsBox.html("59")}else{if(e==0&&a==0){theHoursBox.html(c-1);theMinsBox.html("59");theSecsBox.html("59")}else{if(e==0){theMinsBox.html(a-1);theSecsBox.html("59")}else{theSecsBox.html(e-1)}}}}},1000);});






    });
</script>

<div class="items-count" id="progress_bar"></div><div id="clock-ticker" class="clearfix"><div class="block"><span class="flip-top" id="numdays">0</span><br><span class="label">Days</span></div><div class="block"><span class="flip-top" id="numhours">1</span><br><span class="label">Hours</span></div><div class="block"><span class="flip-top" id="nummins">23</span><br><span class="label">Minutes</span></div><div class="block"><span class="flip-top" id="numsecs">36</span><br><span class="label">Seconds</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please paste your .phtml file

Comment: pasted it. :) thx

Answer (score 6):

You need to use with the RequiredJS implementation, like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery","domReady!"], function ($) {

            function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {returnMath.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);}

            // Settings are here
            var total_items = 50;
            var d = new Date();
            var min_items_left = 12;
            var max_items_left = 20;
            var remaining_items = randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left, max_items_left);
            var min_of_remaining_items = 1;
            var decrease_after = 1.7; 
            var decrease_after_first_item = 0.17; 

            // Davy Jones' Locker

            $.fn.progressbar=function(){var a="<p>Hurry! Only <span class='count'>"+remaining_items+"</span> left in stock.</p>"+"<div class='progressbar'><div style='width:100%'></div></div>";this.addClass('items-count');this.html(a+this.html());updateMeter(this);var b=this;setTimeout(function(){remaining_items--;if(remaining_items<min_of_remaining_items){remaining_items=randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left,max_items_left)}$('.count').css('background-color','#CE0201');$('.count').css('color','#fff');setTimeout(function(){$('.count').css('background-color','#fff');$('.count').css('color','#CE0201')},1000*60*0.03);b.find(".count").text(remaining_items);updateMeter(b)},1000*60*decrease_after_first_item);setInterval(function(){remaining_items--;if(remaining_items<min_of_remaining_items){remaining_items=randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left,max_items_left)}$('.count').css('background-color','#CE0201');$('.count').css('color','#fff');setTimeout(function(){$('.count').css('background-color','#fff');$('.count').css('color','#CE0201')},1000*60*0.03);b.find(".count").text(remaining_items);updateMeter(b)},1000*60*decrease_after)};function updateMeter(a){var b=100*remaining_items/total_items;if(remaining_items<10){a.find('.progressbar div:first').addClass('less-than-ten')}a.find('.progressbar').addClass('active progress-striped');setTimeout(function(){myanimate(a.find('.progressbar div:first'),b);a.find('.progressbar').removeClass('active progress-striped')},1000)}}(jQuery));function myanimate(a,b){var c=0;var d=parseInt(a.closest('.progressbar').css('width'));var e=Math.floor(100*parseInt(a.css('width'))/d);if(e>b){c=e}function frame(){if(e>b){c--}else{c++}a.css('width',c+'%');if(c==b||c<=0||c>=100)clearInterval(f)}var f=setInterval(frame,40)} $(document).ready(function(){$("#progress_bar").progressbar();var tag="ctdn-12-12".match(/\d+/g);var hour=14;var theDaysBox=$("#numdays");var theHoursBox=$("#numhours");var theMinsBox=$("#nummins");var theSecsBox=$("#numsecs");var d=new Date();var n=d.getDay();var date=1;var gg=0;var hh=0;var ii=0;var nsec=0-d.getSeconds();if(nsec<0){nsec=60-d.getSeconds();gg=1}var nmin=0-d.getMinutes()-gg;if(nmin<0){nmin=60-d.getMinutes()-gg;hh=1}var nhrs=14-d.getHours()-hh;if(nhrs<0){nhrs=38-d.getHours()-hh;ii=1}var ndat=date-1;if(ndat<0){var mmon=d.getMonth();ndat=30+date-d.getDate()-ii}theSecsBox.html(nsec);theMinsBox.html(nmin);theHoursBox.html(nhrs);theDaysBox.html(ndat);var refreshId=setInterval(function(){var e=theSecsBox.text();var a=theMinsBox.text();var c=theHoursBox.text();var b=theDaysBox.text();if(e==0&&a==0&&c==0&&b==0){}else{if(e==0&&a==0&&c==0){theDaysBox.html(b-1);theHoursBox.html("23");theMinsBox.html("59");theSecsBox.html("59")}else{if(e==0&&a==0){theHoursBox.html(c-1);theMinsBox.html("59");theSecsBox.html("59")}else{if(e==0){theMinsBox.html(a-1);theSecsBox.html("59")}else{theSecsBox.html(e-1)}}}}},1000);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work..

Comment: Its just a blank page... i even added the inline css above and still blank..

Comment: I simplify the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Part of the script seems to work now (only the timer). Why does the rest still not work? Any fix?

Comment: I've changed my answer to add another dependency that loads your script after the dom.

Comment: That does not change anything.. :/ Still not working.

Comment: Check your console, and try to implement for parts, I guess that your syntax is wrong.

Comment: I updated the code in my Post, tested it again and still, only the timer seems to work but the rest doesnt. If I use the same script in a normal php file for example, it works flawlessly..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59515/discussion-between-rafael-correa-gomes-and-n1njawtf).

Answer (score 0):

Rafaels answer is correct.

However, if you don't want to use requireJS for some obscure reason, just replace $ with jQuery:

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);}

// Settings are here
var total_items = 50;
var d = new Date();
var min_items_left = 12;
var max_items_left = 20;
var remaining_items = randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left, max_items_left);
var min_of_remaining_items = 1;
var decrease_after = 1.7; 
var decrease_after_first_item = 0.17; 

// Davy Jones' Locker
(function(jQuery){jQuery.fn.progressbar=function(){var a="<p>Hurry! Only <span class='count'>"+remaining_items+"</span> left in stock.</p>"+"<div class='progressbar'><div style='width:100%'></div></div>";this.addClass('items-count');this.html(a+this.html());updateMeter(this);var b=this;setTimeout(function(){remaining_items--;if(remaining_items<min_of_remaining_items){remaining_items=randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left,max_items_left)}jQuery('.count').css('background-color','#CE0201');jQuery('.count').css('color','#fff');setTimeout(function(){jQuery('.count').css('background-color','#fff');jQuery('.count').css('color','#CE0201')},1000*60*0.03);b.find(".count").text(remaining_items);updateMeter(b)},1000*60*decrease_after_first_item);setInterval(function(){remaining_items--;if(remaining_items<min_of_remaining_items){remaining_items=randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left,max_items_left)}jQuery('.count').css('background-color','#CE0201');jQuery('.count').css('color','#fff');setTimeout(function(){jQuery('.count').css('background-color','#fff');jQuery('.count').css('color','#CE0201')},1000*60*0.03);b.find(".count").text(remaining_items);updateMeter(b)},1000*60*decrease_after)};function updateMeter(a){var b=100*remaining_items/total_items;if(remaining_items<10){a.find('.progressbar div:first').addClass('less-than-ten')}a.find('.progressbar').addClass('active progress-striped');setTimeout(function(){myanimate(a.find('.progressbar div:first'),b);a.find('.progressbar').removeClass('active progress-striped')},1000)}}(jQuery));function myanimate(a,b){var c=0;var d=parseInt(a.closest('.progressbar').css('width'));var e=Math.floor(100*parseInt(a.css('width'))/d);if(e>b){c=e}function frame(){if(e>b){c--}else{c++}a.css('width',c+'%');if(c==b||c<=0||c>=100)clearInterval(f)}var f=setInterval(frame,40)} jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#progress_bar").progressbar();var tag="ctdn-12-12".match(/\d+/g);var hour=14;var theDaysBox=jQuery("#numdays");var theHoursBox=jQuery("#numhours");var theMinsBox=jQuery("#nummins");var theSecsBox=jQuery("#numsecs");var d=new Date();var n=d.getDay();var date=1;var gg=0;var hh=0;var ii=0;var nsec=0-d.getSeconds();if(nsec<0){nsec=60-d.getSeconds();gg=1}var nmin=0-d.getMinutes()-gg;if(nmin<0){nmin=60-d.getMinutes()-gg;hh=1}var nhrs=14-d.getHours()-hh;if(nhrs<0){nhrs=38-d.getHours()-hh;ii=1}var ndat=date-1;if(ndat<0){var mmon=d.getMonth();ndat=30+date-d.getDate()-ii}theSecsBox.html(nsec);theMinsBox.html(nmin);theHoursBox.html(nhrs);theDaysBox.html(ndat);var refreshId=setInterval(function(){var e=theSecsBox.text();var a=theMinsBox.text();var c=theHoursBox.text();var b=theDaysBox.text();if(e==0&&a==0&&c==0&&b==0){}else{if(e==0&&a==0&&c==0){theDaysBox.html(b-1);theHoursBox.html("23");theMinsBox.html("59");theSecsBox.html("59")}else{if(e==0&&a==0){theHoursBox.html(c-1);theMinsBox.html("59");theSecsBox.html("59")}else{if(e==0){theMinsBox.html(a-1);theSecsBox.html("59")}else{theSecsBox.html(e-1)}}}}},1000);});
```

But I have to say you can better use the requireJS format and look into that.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work.. I would like to use the answer from "rafael", however it doesnt seem to fully work.. Part of the code still does not work.

Comment: Check your javascript console for clues